# Integrating a product of Heaviside step functions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I would like to deal with the following integral:

$$ f(\vec y) = \int\limits_{\mathbb R^3}\text{d}^3\vec x\, H(a-|\vec x|)\,H(b-|\vec x+\vec y|) \quad a,b>0 $$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

I think changing to spherical coordinates ($x,\theta,\varphi$) might be helpful, then assuming that $\vec x \cdot \vec y = |\vec x||\vec y|\, \cos(\theta)$ might help to simplify the $|\vec x+\vec y|$. However, this did not lead me to a result.

edit: could partial integration be useful? i.e. integrating the first $H$, turning the other into a delta function..?

edit 2: as for convergence, I am pretty sure it converges. I have a result for when $a=b$ (sadly no proof), and now I would like to generalize it:

$$ f(\vec y) = \int\limits_{\mathbb R^3}\text{d}^3\vec x\, H(a-|\vec x|)\,H(a-|\vec x+\vec y|) = \frac{2\pi }{3} a^3 \left(1-\frac{|\vec y|}{2a}\right)^2 \left(\frac{|\vec y|}{2a}+2\right) H\left(1-\frac{|\vec y|}{2a}\right)   $$

Comment: Do we even know if it converges?

Comment: @AEngineer Good question, yes I think so. I edited my question to address this.

Comment: Move $y$ to $-e_1$. Find the solutions to $\{ x, |x|=a, |x-e_1|=b\}$ you'll obtain  two volumes of the form $Vol( |x| \le a, x_1 \le r) = \int_{-a}^r \int_{ x_2^2+x_3^2 \le a^2-x_1^2} dx_2dx_3 dx_1$

Comment: Can't you convert this product of Heaviside functions into a sum ? I refer here to the two ways one can write the "rect_{[a,b]}" function : $rect_{[a,b]}(x) = H(x-a)H(b-x)= (H(x-a)+H(b-x))/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Term $H(a-|x|)$ defines a sphere at origin with radius $a$. Term $H(b-|x+y|)$ defines a sphere at $y$ with radius $b$. You are basically asking for a volume of intersection. [Which is](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html):

$$
\frac{\pi}{12|y|}\Big(a+b-|y|\Big)^2\Big(y^2+2|y|(a+b)-3(a-b)^2\Big)H(a+b-|y|)
$$

Comment: This is a very interesting way to look at this, thank you very much! I just checked, for $a=b$, your result coincides with the expression I wrote in my post. Perfect!

Comment: By the way, the formula isn't working when $a>|y|+b$ or $b>|y|+a$. In that case volume of intersectipn is the volume of the smallest sphere.